# How to deal with duplicates using Excel/R?

Tags: r, excel

I have data that looks like this in excel:

```
Name    Value
A        10
B        20
A        30
C        40
E        50
D        60
E        70
F        80
A        90
B        100
```

And it goes down for hundreds of rows, while i know how to delete duplicates, is there a way in excel or r to differentiate the duplicates?

My final table would ideally look like this

```
Name    Value
A       10
B       20
A_1     30
C       40
E       50
D       60
E_1     70
F       80
A_2     90
B_1     100
```

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Filter-for-unique-values-or-remove-duplicate-values-ccf664b0-81d6-449b-bbe1-8daaec1e83c2

Comment: Thanks for the link, but this is only to change the font/style of the duplicates. The way i want to do it is to add (_n) to the duplicates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this formula:

```
=A2& IF(COUNTIF($A$2:$A2,A2)=1,"","_"&COUNTIF($A$2:$A2,A2)-1)
```

See below screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

We can use `make.unique` in `R`

```
df$Name <- make.unique(df$Name, sep='_')
```